# iTunes 12.1 - Stuttering when playing music

Tags: itunes, windows, music

I've just upgraded to the latest version of iTunes (12.1) for Windows -- the first proper 64-bit edition of the software for Windows -- and now all my music has stutters, pops and clicks when playing music.

I have an extremely well-specced machine.

- Intel Core i7
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760
- 16GB RAM
- Windows 8.1 64-bit

Latest drivers. I even ensured I reset my machine after the installation. It happens with all music files, from MP3 to AAC.

What's going on? Every other music player on my system plays the same files perfectly fine.

Comment: What format is your music in?

Comment: It's in MP3 format mostly, but it's every single song I'm playing... from thousands.

Comment: Exactly the same problem with the same version of iTunes. 8 GB RAM
Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: Same hardware, software and problem. My guess: not properly handling the cache (aka buffer). Regular files are "streamed" from the HDD, this streaming may cache the whole file or chunks of it. The cache is probably too small and sometimes for a short interval the data is simply not there, causing these noises. I could not find the option to configure this, hopefully they will fix it in the next version, until then: use other player (or let me know if you find the config option for it).

Comment: @Trylks When you say "same hardware", what are you referring to?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I mean I hacked your computer and I use it to listen to music. Joking, I mean [this](http://imgur.com/V7vcojp).

Comment: @Trylks ;) Just wondered if we had the same graphics card (in case that was the common thread), but we don't (although very similar!). Weird stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have released an update to iTunes that fixes this problem.

**iTunes 12.1.1** (and higher) should solve any issues you're having (it did for me).

Answer (score 2):

Many iTunes for Windows users had the same problem with the recent upgrade, myself included. To fix the problem (it worked for me), download and install the iTunes 12.1 for Windows that is supposed to be for older video cards. But don't let that last part fool you. I have a card less than 12 months old and this solution worked wonderfully. Here is the link to the download from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1784?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US.